Use Quadmath and boost::multiprecision with CMake
I started writing a CMake based project, and I have installed the boost library and Quadmath, using Arch Linux and GCC.
When I use:
#include <boost/multiprecision/float128.hpp>

It raises the error that 'quadmath.h' is not found.
But it is definetly present in my system under /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/14.2.1/include.
I tried to write my own FindQuadmath.cmake with this content:
include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)

include_directories("/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/14.2.1/include")

find_path(Quadmath_INCLUDE_DIR NAMES quadmath.h
    PATHS "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/14.2.1/include")
find_library(Quadmath_LIBRARY NAMES quadmath)

message("Quadmath_INCLUDE_DIR: ${Quadmath_INCLUDE_DIR}")
message("Quadmath_LIBRARY: ${Quadmath_LIBRARY}")

add_library(Quadmath SHARED IMPORTED ${Quadmath_LIBRARY})
target_include_directories(Quadmath INTERFACE ${Quadmath_INCLUDE_DIR})

set_property(TARGET Quadmath PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${Quadmath_LIBRARY})
set_property(TARGET Quadmath PROPERTY INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${Quadmath_INCLUDE_DIR})

find_package_handle_standard_args(Quadmath DEFAULT_MSG Quadmath_LIBRARY Quadmath_INCLUDE_DIR)

In the top level Cmake, I include this FindQuadmath.
Current project structure:
├── cmake
│   └── FindQuadmath.cmake
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── conanfile.txt
├── conan_profiles
│   └── phd
├── README.md
├── requirements.txt
├── solvers
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   └── heat_transfer_explicit_scheme
│       ├── CMakeLists.txt
│       ├── include
│       │   └── heat_transfer_explicit_scheme.hpp
│       └── src
│           └── heat_transfer_explicit_scheme.cpp
└── tests

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.30)

project(phd_project CXX)

include(cmake/FindQuadmath.cmake)

find_package(Boost REQUIRED)

add_subdirectory(solvers/)

Neither I, nor boost can find headers such as <quadmath.h> and others from this lib.
How do I fix this and link Quadmath with CMake?

Tried it some time ago and not found any solution

What version of boost do you have? Maybe https://github.com/boostorg/multiprecision/pull/634. Also throw away your find module, libquadmath is a part of GCC and doesn't require any search logic.

Also if you have multiple installations of GCC make sure CMake picked up the correct one and don't forget to delete cmake cache.

@Osyotr in boost/version.h #define BOOST_VERSION 108600, #define BOOST_LIB_VERSION "1_86" and gcc (GCC) 14.2.1 20240910

@Osyotr as far as I can see  "-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 14.2.1". In boost::multiprecision headers don't see changes from github.com/boostorg/multiprecision/pull/634

I have multiple issues.

usage of some boost::multiprecision::float128 requires adding explicit link option:

add_link_options(
    -lquadmath)

For some reason, Boost CMake target does not encapsulate it? After that, the code can be compiled and executed, thus, it is a solution for the issue from this thread. This note I found here: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/libs/math/example/float128_example.cpp

in Qt Creator, I still have a lexical/preprocessor issue to line with code using <quadmath.h>, but I posted the question about that here: clangd false positive '<quadmath.h>' not found

